# How to access _path property within HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring-boot

l would like to access the `_path` property within `HttpMessageNotReadableException`, but I do not know from which method or methods to do this. How can I access it?

My JDK version is JDK8 and My Spring Boot version is 2.1.4.

Comment: Can you please give feedback on my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```java
e.getHttpInputMessage().getHeaders().getLocation().getPath()
```

I'll leave it to you to check for `null` where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via `((MismatchedInputException)exception.getCause()).getPath()` where `exception` is of type `HttpMessageNotReadableException`

Of course this depends on the cause being of type `MismatchedInputException`, I am not 100% sure about all possible cause types, but you can essentially define individual logic for each possible type to extract `_path` whenever possible.

I was able to captured and investigate `_path` within the following exception handler method;

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public void handleBadRequestException(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception) {
    ((MismatchedInputException)exception.getCause()).getPath()  // do whatever with the result
    ...
}
```

But better to be safe about the possibility of `null`, maybe `cause` can be `null`, so add a null check for that before getting `_path`